# Putting parameter drop down, and "apply changes" in preview view

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using the standalone crystal reports (no .net or visual basic) to generate reports, and I'm trying to figure out a way to put the parameter selection and "apply changes" button actually in the window instead of in the "Parameters" tab to the left.

Is there a way to do this or some way to export the report for a user to easily have this ability? I feel its something very simple I missed or its not possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the window? means? where you want to place the parameters tab?

Comment: I think you are referring to the parameter panel on the left within the preview panel. To my knowledge what you are asking is not possible. But I hope someone answers here and proves me wrong because that would be quite useful.

Comment: @Siva I am referring to the "Preview" view. The parameters show up on the left (between "Groups" and "Find") , and the actual document preview in the center.

Comment: I doubt the possibility of your requirement with crystal reports as a standalone.... my knowledge is not sufficient to answer... to the extent I know it is not possible... as it is the feature of CR also you are using standalone crystal reports.